# Where does the "user" image come from in the blame window for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I was recently moving around through VS Code trying to become familiar with the UI and all of it's ins and outs. Along the way, I wanted to check the blame for a file I was working in. I accomplished this by clicking on the file annotations button (highlighted):

[image]

When I did, I hovered over the time and was greeted by a "toast" styled "tooltip" if you will:

[image: Screenshot of the time and "user" image.]

I'm connected to an Azure Dev Ops repo, and my profile picture on there is the same as here, so that made me curious. Where does this "user" image come from?

Comment: User icons for services like StackOverflow, GitHub, … either provide an API to fetch the user image based on username/email, or another source could be gravatar.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT thanks for the reminder! :) I haven't had a chance to verify this but I'll do my best to check it today. I'm 100% positive that my profile picture on DevOps is already set to the exact same image as it is here.

Answer (score 2):

> Where does the “user” image come from in the blame window for VS Code?

When you connect to an Azure DevOps, this "user" image come from in the blame window is comes from the [Azure Devops profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-your-preferences?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page):

[image]

[image]

Comment: So after reviewing my profile in DevOps, my picture is already set there yet I'm getting the little "wooden robot" image in VS Code. Is there an additional setting I need to look at?

Comment: @Tacoタコス, You mean you have the different picture from profile and VS code? If yes, how about this isssue now?

Comment: Yes, it is different between my DevOps profile and VS code; however I'm not sure I understand your second question.